# Debugging VB script in ArcGIS Field Calcultor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I work in ArcMap and I would like to use Field Calcultor (VB script) but my script is not working. The message is:

> there was a failure during processing check the geoprocessing results
>   window for details

I did it and it always said that I have syntax error but I don't know why. All of my fields are integer.

Here is the script:

```
Dim test

if [Field_1] > 50 then
test = 5
elseif [Field_1] = 50 then
test = 6
elseif [Field_1]  < 50 then
test = 7

end if
```

Comment: depending on your ArcMap version you may not need the "Dim test", try without it

Comment: I use 10.4 version
I tried without it  but it does not work.

Comment: You may check for null value in "field_1" and if any set a condition for that in your script, also did you properly set the field calculator (check the "show codeblock" and fill the "test" value in lower text box) , if after that it still didn't work I'm out of idea...

Comment: That's actually works. Thank you for your help!